# Rendered first Javascript before PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Assuming in `PHP` file there're :

```
    function printAllRows(){
      for( everyrows in db){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td> $_POST['..'] <td>";
         echo "<td> $_POST['..'] <td>";
         echo "<tr>"; 
      }

     }


function printSpecifRows($keyword){
  .....
 }
```

// When the page loads for the first time

```
 if ($db->preRow() >0){ // count rows in DB , if there already show them as table 
printAllRows();
}
```

At the same time , there is

```
<input type="text" name="keywoard"  />
<input type="submit" name="find" value="search" />
```

If the user enter the keyword press the button , then just show the rows match the keyword!

so :

```
if( $_POST["find"]){
 ?>

 <script>
 // first clear the current DOM table
  document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML="";
 </script>

 <?php


 // then print again! according to printSpecifRows($keyword) 
 function printSpecifRows($keyword){
  .....
 }}
```

But the problem here is that `JS` is rendered first before `PHP` , so `printSpecifRows($keyword)`  won't  never be reached , any idea. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Do you reaslize PHP and JavaScript do not run at the same time? Why would you right out JavaScirpt to clear the table on a new page load?

Comment: js is not "rendered" before PHP. php executes on the server, js executes on the client. they're completely different environment.

Comment: thank you , @epascarello ,@MarcB , i just learn many  new things from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are massively over-complicating things. Get rid of the `<script>` entirely. There is no need or point in involving JS here.

Just change the PHP so it doesn't output *all* the data in the first place if you don't want it on the page.

```
if ($_POST["find"]){
    printSpecifRows($_POST["find"]);
} else {
    printAllRows();
}
```

Comment: it's good practice to use `if (isset($_POST["find"])){...` to avoid undefined index error, (or use `filter_input`)

Comment: oh my bloody sexy gf, My thought is so deep that i messed everything , thank you so much Quentin. And about XSS why so?? in simple explanation , i'm rookie :) thanks again

Comment: @febri23 About XSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting There are clear examples.