# How to render the content of React Quill without the html markup?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-quill

I managed to get my Quill working, but now I wanted to display the contents from the editor without the html markup. I tried using [react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html) npm package, it was working fine before but now it is no longer maintained and gives me a error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-render-html'. /path/to/module
implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-render-html` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-render-html';
```

also it shows up with html markup. So i tried using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) , [htmr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmr) , [html-to-react](https://github.com/aknuds1/html-to-react) npm packages , it works perfectly for single elements but it is not working for multiple elements.
So i tried console.log to see what i am receiving from backend which gave me this

```
<p>&lt;h2&gt;Hello&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;how are you ? &lt;/p&gt; &lt;h2&gt;Hello&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;how are you ? &lt;/p&gt; &lt;h2&gt;Hello&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;how are you ? &lt;/p&gt; &lt;h2&gt;Hello&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;how are you ? &lt;/p&gt; &lt;h2&gt;Hello&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;how are you ? &lt;/p&gt;
```

Now i wanted to render this without the html markup , so i did again console.log to see whether it is getting converted properly by doing

```
  //import renderHtml from 'htmr';
  //import renderHtml from 'html-to-react';

    import renderHtml from 'react-html-parser';
 
  console.log(renderHtml(${blog.excerpt}))
```

and ultimately it gave me this

```
<h2>Hello</h2><p>how are you ? </p>
<h2>Hello</h2><p>how are you ? </p> 
<h2>Hello</h2><p>how are you ? </p> 
<h2>Hello</h2><p>how are you ? </p> 
<h2>Hello</h2><p>how are you ? </p>
```

I also tried with `dangerouslysetinnerhtml`
but it isn't working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your server response, the HTML tag is escaped. You need to escape it first before passing to HTML parser.

You can use [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) to decode the server response. The easiest way is to replace all `&lt;` and `&gt;` characters.

```js
const decodedHtml = htmlEntities.decode(html)
// or
const decodedHtml = html.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>')

return htmr(decodedHtml)
```

Comment: I have an another question , 
When i tried passing the html code 

`import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const ReactQuill = dynamic( ()=> import('react-quill'), {ssr:false} )
import '../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

const ReactQuillEditor = () =>{
       <ReactQuill placeholder="Write here, minimum of 200 charaters is required" 
modules={CreateBlog.modules} formats={ CreateBlog.formats } >
       </ReactQuill>
  }
`


It is giving me a whole new error, is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: This is happening only when I send any block of code from editor to database & trying to show the contents

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem just paste one line
 `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:value }} />`

here value is the HTML that you got from react-quill.