# How to load an HTML document in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on my website's Terms And Conditions page. I have the actual document as a `.docx` file but using Google Docs I am able to export it as an `.html` file.

The generated file is it's own standalone HTML element, with a custom stylesheet that Google loads in. It looks like this (summarised):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <style type="text/css">
       @import url('https://themes.googleusercontent.com/fonts/css?kit=fpjTOVmNbO4Lz34iLyptLUXza5VhXqVC6o75Eld_V98');.lst-kix_list_1-3>li:before{content:"\0025cf  "}.lst-kix_l.......
    </style>
</head>
<body class="c16">
    <!-- a bunch of elements with custom classes -->
</body>
</html>
```

How can I safely load this document inside my React component, with the included stylesheet?

```
class TermsAndConditionsPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
       // my custom React code here
       // the HTML doc here...
    }
}
```

I could just paste the contents of the `<body>` tag inside, but then I lose the styling. Is it possible to load the stylesheet only when the user lands on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert html in react component. This will render the whole html inside the `div` tag.

```
const content = `<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <style type="text/css">
       @import url('https://themes.googleusercontent.com/fonts/css?kit=fpjTOVmNbO4Lz34iLyptLUXza5VhXqVC6o75Eld_V98');.lst-kix_list_1-3>li:before{content:"\0025cf  "}.lst-kix_l.......
    </style>
</head>
<body class="c16">
    <div>Test</div>
</body>
</html>`


class TermsAndConditionsPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}/>
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
>   it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a `cross-site scripting > (XSS) attack`. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
>   to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a __html
>   key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would work. Is the XSS risk coming from the fact that the HTML or stylesheet you insert could be hosted somewhere out of your control?

Comment: Please go through this answer to know more about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644499/what-does-it-mean-when-they-say-react-is-xss-protected

Comment: I used your answer but for clarity purposes I used the webpack plugin `html-loader` to load my HTML file as a string in a more convenient way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If looking for the easiest, quickest method, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` will do the trick as the other answer mentions.

If you don't mind some manual work, you could use online tools like https://premailer.io/

1. copy over all CSS declarations in the `import`ed sheet into `head` area within `style` tag
2. copy the entire `html` document into the input area at https://premailer.io/
3. hit convert

You'll then end up with the complete `html` document with every CSS style inlined, which you could use as JSX.