# How to fetch the API when we have data in html format in react project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, api

I am using ckeditor for inserting blog contact in django. When I integrated CKeditor with my django admin then I got API Set, [click](https://i.ibb.co/f4DXQtq/testimg.png) here to see the screenshots of the data.
In image you can see there is sub_title_second given as a html format. I tried to fetch this API as a normal way [click](https://codeshare.io/2W3MZM) here to check the code. But it coming in below format

```
p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 24pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: georgia, palatino, serif;">"I never regretted being an architect&rdquo;- Ratan Tata</span></strong></span></p> <p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-family: georgia, palatino, serif;">Ratan Tata is well known as an industrialist, philanthropist, and former chairman of Tata Sons.</span></span></p>
```

How can we fetch this as UI format? or [Click](https://i.ibb.co/YXg3BWZ/formate.png) here to see image

Comment: I think what you looking for is https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml; `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.sub_title_second}}/>`. Make sure you are protecting your code from XSS when using this method.

Comment: @MrT Ok this is working but now the question is How to protect it with XSS?

Comment: You are not protecting with XSS, you need to protect _against_ XSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644499/what-does-it-mean-when-they-say-react-is-xss-protected

Comment: @MrT Now Am very clear with all this topic and everything is set well. Thanks!!