# How to sanitize request url in Next Js to prevent XSS attacks

Tags: javascript, security, next.js, xss

We ran security vulnerability scan on our next js app.It detected XSS with following result

```
GET /../\"> HTTP/1.0
Host:xxx.xxx.xx.x:3000

HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
location: /../\">/
Refresh: 0;url=/../\">/
Date: TUE, 30 Jan 2024 02:36:50 GMT
Connection: close
/../\">/
```

To mitigate this vulnerability, it suggested to sanitize request url.
As per my understanding the issue is with hiting url with script characters E.g. `http://localhost:3000/../">`
Is my understanding correct and how we can mitigate it?

Comment: This is generally what you should be doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644499/what-does-it-mean-when-they-say-react-is-xss-protected