# How to use the context variables passed from Django in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am having a method in views.py as follows:

```
def index(self, request):
    initial = get_initial()
    context = {"context" : initial_topics}
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

How do I access the "context" dict in javascript ?? 
Like in my $(function(){});

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access the context variable inside the HTML `script` tag.

Still, some rules apply:

1. If the context variable is a string, surround the context variable in quotes.
2. If the context variable is a dict or a list, convert them to json in your view and use the `escapejs` filter. You can also use the `safe` filter but with caution.

---

**Warning:** Never use `safe` filter on untrusted data (such as data submitted by a user). Always sanitize the data (escape unsafe characters) before using the `safe` filter. [Read about XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15755323/1925257) to learn more.

---

You should convert the dict and list variables to json in your views because if there are any Python specific keywords, such as `True` or `False` or `None` in the dict, JS won't understand them and will raise an error.

In JS, the equivalent keywords are `true`, `false` and `null`. So, converting dicts and lists to json will transform the data into a JS compatible format.

Example:

```
import json 

def my_view(...):
    my_string = 'hello'
    my_list = [...]
    my_dict = {...}
    
    context = {'my_list': json.dumps(my_list), 'my_dict': json.dumps(my_dict)}
    return ...
```

```js
var my_string = '{{ my_string }}';

// for lists and dicts, use JSON.parse() to convert
// them into JS objects
var my_list = JSON.parse('{{ my_list|escapejs }}');
var my_dict = JSON.parse('{{ my_dict|escapejs }}');
```

Comment: Thanks. I am passing a dict {"one" : 1, "two":2} like this for example. after doing json.dumps. In my javascript end, whenI just did alert("{{context}}" it gave "{&quot;one&quot;: 1, &quot;two&quot;: 2}". Plase gelp

Comment: @Trickycoder Hello. Sorry, my answer had some mistakes. I've fixed them and edited the whole answer and have added more explanation. Hope this helps you this time.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Even when the context variable is just a string you should still use `escapejs`. Otherwise a Python string like `"foo \" \' bar"` would not be correctly represented in JS

Answer (score 3):

If the javascript code lies in the html template being rendered, you can use it in the normal way `{{ context }}`. Else, declare a global in the html template and access that global from your separate js file.

Comment: How can I apply this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to apply? The 1st method (JS code within html) or the 2nd (JS file separate)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert into Javascript then make sure to use escapejs, and in more advanced cases you may need to use JSON.parse;

```
var context = "{{ context }}"
```

If you are still having issues, then try;

```
var context = JSON.parse("{{ context|escapejs }}");
```

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the
>   JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional
>   reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the
>   resulting object before it is returned.
>   [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Can we use var my_dict = JSON.parse("{{ my_dict|safe }}"); ?