# Django how to correctly acces the context array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

My question is similar to the these previous questions, however I can't seem to make my code work:

[How can I pass my context variables to a javascript file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683922/how-can-i-pass-my-context-variables-to-a-javascript-file-in-django)

[How to use the context variables passed from Django in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305020/how-to-use-the-context-variables-passed-from-django-in-javascript)

I have a list of lists, containing data of the form:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, ...] [210, 346, 331, 402, ...] [...] ...]
```

where the first list represents the number of each taken sample.  I'm passing this data to my HTML file using a class that looks like:

```
class IndexView_charts(generic.TemplateView):
    """
    IndexView:
    """
    module = 'IndexView'
    template_name = charts_temp_name #variable for the template

data = ##extra code here to fetch data

def get_queryset(self):
    log(self.module, 'get_queryset', file=__file__)
    return self.data

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['data'] = self.data
    return context
```

And in the template, I can access the variable data as follows for example and it shows up on the webpage:

```
<h1> {{data.0}} </h1>
```

now, I'd like to access it in my script. In the same file I have the following code:

```
var chartData = {{ data }};
... some more code here ...
data:chartData[1]
```

but I don't get the charts that I would like. If i change the occurrences of chartData[x] into lists containing some dummy data, the script works. So the problem lies at accessing the data.

Comment: Have your tried using `escapejs` built in tag, e.g. `'{{ python_object|escapejs }}';`?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the context array is not being parsed correctly to `js` as an array. If my commented suggestion doesn't work then you can try to use `tojson` template-tag to convert python list to js array.

For example,

```
var mylist = {{mylist|tojson}};
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
```