# How do I pass a variable from Django's render method's context param to a javascript script on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, django

For context here, I am experienced with JavaScript but new to Django.

Goal: Log the contents of a Django context variable in the browser's console using JavaScript. Specifically I'd like to log the contents of `context` in the Django render method I write below.

In `script.js` I have `console.log("hey", foo)` which I expect to output the contents of a variable I pass into the Django render method. It gives me an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

I found two StackOverflow threads that *seem* to answer my question re: how to do this correctly. Neither worked.

In (1) [How can I pass my context variables to a javascript file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683922/how-can-i-pass-my-context-variables-to-a-javascript-file-in-django), the answer from user Brian Neal claims I can deliver the Django variable into a javascript script at the top of the html file Django uses to render the page. Here is how I tried his answer:

Django's render method says...

```
def page(request):
    bar = "a"
    doohickey = "b"
    context = {'foo': bar,'baz': doohickey}
    return render(request, 'myPage.html',context=context)
```

Then in `myPage.html` I say:

```
{% load static %}
{% block js %}
    <script>var foo = {{ foo|safe }}; console.log("aliens");</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And `script.js` says `console.log("hey", foo)`

But I get the error message written above.

In (2), [How to use the context variables passed from Django in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305020/how-to-use-the-context-variables-passed-from-django-in-javascript), a similar problem is presented and answered. The ticked answer from user xyres says the same process will (seemingly) work for me.

*Both threads say to use double {{ }} tags to pass the django variable to a JavaScript script.*

However, I am clearly doing something wrong in `myPage.html`, because "aliens" does not print to the console. I've been through 8 threads and none of them tell me what to do.

I also found a blog [Safely Including Data for JavaScript in a Django Template](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/) which claims using the answers I linked to on StackOverflow would create an opportunity for hackers. So I don't want that.

I also found [an Edureka page with an answer to the same question I have](https://www.edureka.co/community/79368/how-to-use-django-variable-in-javascript-file) and did this in myPage.html -- note the  tag is now *outside* of the `{% block js %}` part:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<script>var foo = {{ foo|safe }}; console.log("aliens");</script>
{% block js %}
    <script>var foo = {{ foo|safe }}; console.log("aliens");</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
```

No change though.

Another update:

When I write `context = {"magic": "wizard"}` and pass that to the frontend, `<script>console.log("aliens"); var something = {{ magic }}; console.log(something);</script>` gives me an error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'`. Upon investigation, I'm closer than I've ever been to making it work. The code is embedded with bugs: `var something = &quot;wizard&quot;;`

Comment: And what your rendered page looks like? Has the variable foo been inserted in the code?

Comment: The rendered page has html. What part of the rendered page would help answer the question? I can't really post it, it's too long. And, "foo" doesn't make it from the ```context``` variable to the ```script.js``` file where it is supposed to be logged to the console. The real contents of "foo" will eventually be inserted into the page.

Comment: Well, the source html part with the <script> tags that you showed earlier, but now rendered through Django. It should read var foo = a , isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the context variables passed from Django in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305020/how-to-use-the-context-variables-passed-from-django-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the django variable is a string, quotes are needed.
so it would be like:

```
var foo = "{{foo}}";
```

Comment: ```const foo = "{{foo|safe}}" ``` finally did it, thanks