# How to pull a variable using PHP to repull information on refresh

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the page to save what data to pull up once I refresh. How I figured I would do this is to just re-pull the $ID variable using PHP. But I can't seem to get it to work.

```
echo "<center><b><p style='color: green'>Order Status: " . $row['status'] . "</p></b></center><br><br>";
    echo "<center><p>Address: " . $row['address'] . "</p></center><br>";
    echo "<center><p>Telephone: " . $row['tel'] . "</p></center><br>";
    echo "<center><p>Email: " . $row['email'] . "</p></center><br>";
    echo "<center><b><p>Order ID: " . $row['ID'] . "</p></b></center><br>";
    echo "<center><p>Submitted on: " . $row['date'] . "</p></center>";
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo "<fieldset>
      <button onclick='window.location='http://qdeliver.ca/fetchorder.php?id='<?php echo $_GET['ID'];?>' name='refresh' type='submit' id='contact-submit' data-submit='...Refreshing'>Refresh Order</button>
    </fieldset>";
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "save the data to pull up"?  What do you mean by "re-pull the $ID variable"?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: why don't you used form to save data? Also `name attribute` t send all data

Comment: So I'm trying to take the $row['ID'] info and have it input into the refresh button, so when I refresh it will refresh to .php?id=$ID

Comment: Anyone have any idea what can be done here?

Comment: So what exactly isn't working in your solution? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What isn't working is the variable wont place itself into .php?id=$ID once I hit the refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the syntax highlighter on your code, it's clear that your `<?php echo $_GET['ID'];?>` is part of the string in `echo`, and won't be run.

Use string concatenation:

```
echo "<fieldset>
  <button onclick=\"window.location='http://qdeliver.ca/fetchorder.php?id=" .  intval($_GET['ID']) . "\" name='refresh' type='submit' id='contact-submit' data-submit='...Refreshing'>Refresh Order</button>
</fieldset>";
```

**NOTE**: Your original code is insecure as not filtering user input will open your script to [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting). I've added an `intval()` call to ensure the ID will always be an integer.