# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in my code

Tags: javascript

i have tried another code by store whole url in variable.It's give me error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

```
<?php
$url=$item['item_url'];
$title=$item["item_title"];
$str_url='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$url.'&amp;t='.$title;
?>
<script>
    var str_url = "'<?php echo $str_url; ?>'";
    var title = "'<?php echo $title; ?>'";
    var social_icon ="<div class='display-social-button'><a class='uk-icon-button uk-icon-facebook' onclick='popupCenter('"+ str_url + "','" + title + "','450','450');' href='javascript:void(0);'></a></div>"; 


</script>
```

Comment: I think its not about this line. can provide the whole function?

Comment: `popupCenter(http://www.facebook.com`... the URL should be in a quote or double quote. However, you should post the whole function.

Comment: be careful this code is vulnerable to xss. What is xss: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting How to prevent it in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Answer (score -2):

You need to add quotes around the variable in the onclick

```
var social_icon ="<div class='display-social-button'><a class='uk-icon-button uk-icon-facebook' onclick='popupCenter(\"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+ str_url + "&amp;t="+ title + ","+title+"\",450,450);' href='javascript:void(0);'></a></div>";
```

That said, it isn't recommend to use onclick events at all for anchors. I'd recommend using the href and [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) tags of an anchor.

Comment: There's no issue with the line in the question. There's some issue in the lines before this.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Wrong. When he clicks the anchor, it will trigger the invalid Javascript and throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Rahul, the line in the question has a problem missing quotes for the URL. If you check it in js, it doesn't occur. But when it be rendered to HTML, it will occur when clicking on the button.

Comment: Ohh yes, thank you for pointing that out, I'm sorry for the stupid downvote.I guess I can retract it once the answer is edited.