# How to pass var obj to the method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The code is as below:

```
<el-input v-model="ruleForm.vol" @change="calValue(vol,ruleForm.vol)">
  <template slot="suffix">{{ vol }}</template>
</el-input>

data() {
  return {
    vol: 0,
    ruleForm: {
       vol: 0
    }      
  }
},
methods: {
  calValue(objCal, obj) {
    console.log(objCal)
    console.log(eval(obj))
    objCal = eval(obj)
    console.log(objCal)
  }
}
```

When I type 1+1 in the input box, the suffix is not changed. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly (something you might already know, but...), avoid using `eval` in production, especially when user input plays a factor. This opens your app up to different security vulnerabilities, here namely script injection and cross-site scripting (read more about [XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting)).

Secondly, you're not setting a new value for `vol` here, hence it doesn't change. Inside your `calValue` method, make sure to set a new value for it.

```
<el-input v-model="ruleForm.vol" @change="calValue(vol, ruleForm.vol)">
  <template slot="suffix">{{ vol }}</template>
</el-input>

data() {
  return {
    vol: 0,
    ruleForm: {
       vol: 0
    }      
  }
},
methods: {
  calValue(objCal, obj) {
    console.log(objCal)
    console.log(eval(obj))
    objCal = eval(obj)
    this.vol = objCal
  }
}
```

**(!) But** an even better approach for this is to use Vue's [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). With those, your code would now look like:

```
<el-input v-model="vol">
  <template slot="suffix">{{ result }}</template>
</el-input>

data() {
  return {
    vol: 0
  }
},
computed: {
  result () {
    return eval(this.vol)
  }
}
```

Notice how you don't need a method and a `@change` listener, since `v-model` already changes the mapped value on every `@input` behind the scenes (more on this [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/)).

Again - if you're building a calculator or something similar and wish to be aware of security, you'd probably parse the user input `1 + 1` into `{argument} {operator} {argument}` and then call a method based on the `operator` that the user used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: great thx @Kano !!!, I'm new hand of Vue.js. Computed properties is the right solution. And u r right, there is security issue if user input unexpected value. I need to use regular expression to restrict the input format.  Thanks again!