# Do HTML disappear between 2 opening and closing PHP tags?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print forms with php in a for loop, my goal is to print buttons as much as I have array elements, but when I try to do this in browser, html forms does not show on the page, or in the source.

```
<div class="col text-center">
    <?php
    $max = count($array);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
        $item = $array[$i];
        $item = str_replace(' ', '', $item);
        ?>
        <form method="GET" action="page.php?ders=<?php echo $item;?>" target="_blank" name="f1">
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $item;?>">
             <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><?php echo $item;?> &raquo;</a>
        </form>
        <br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

When I run this on console with command php script.php it shows all of the forms with correct values, and when I put the output on a page.html it shows the buttons but I need page.php and php has to render the html forms on the page.php on browser, am I missing something?

Comment: From what I understand, you have a file whose PHP script is not working, right?

Comment: No I have it working but I thought my variables were right now I will check the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. I will try and point them out line by line and with an alternative

```
$max = count($array);
```

Unless you have already checked that `$array` is present, the above line should be checked. If you do not, you could end up with an error:

```
$max = (isset($array)) ? count($array) : 0;
```

These two lines could be compacted from:

```
$item = $array[$i];
$item = str_replace(' ', '', $item);
```

To the following. This is really a personal thing. Note: Later you render `$item`. If `$item` can be *anything* you would need to use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to ensure your page is not vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting).

```
$item = str_replace(' ', '', $array[$i]);
```

Now this line is very interesting. You are creating a new form for each `$item`. Is that really what you wanted to do?

```
<form method="GET" action="page.php?ders=<?php echo $item;?>" target="_blank" name="f1">
```

Either way, did you really mean to include the attribute `target="_blank"`?

The next issue is you have given each form the same name with `name="f1"`. This will more than likely cause issues if not now, then with any expansion. Something like the following would be better:

```
<form method="GET" action="page.php?ders=<?=$item?>" name="f1<?=$item?>">
```

This next line I belive is hinting at what you really want. Basically, it makes the rest of your code seem pointless unless you really need a form submitted to `page.php`, which I do not think you do as you have already set a query string variable `ders` to the form `action` attribute.

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><?php echo $item;?> &raquo;</a>
```

I think you could have had the following and removed pretty much everything else:

```
 <a href="page.php?ders=<?=$item?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><?=$item?> &raquo;</a>
```

Based on what I think you are trying to do, you should be able to re-write this as:

```
<div class="col text-center">
<?php
    $max = (isset($array)) ? count($array) : 0;
    if (! $max) {
        echo 'No items in array to render!';
    } else {
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $item = str_replace(' ', '', $array[$i]);
            // make the following one line
            echo '<a href="page.php?ders='.$item.'" 
                    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
                    target="_blank">'.$item.' &raquo;</a>
                    <br />';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem was that I was getting an empty array because of a mistake, now that I have the array my main problem is fixed, but you have pointed out many good points and many redundant things I've done, I'll fix them, appreciate it.

Comment: @handsomejack : You are welcome. BTW, Pandora will always belong to the outlaws :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col text-center">
    <?php
        foreach($array as $value):
            $item = str_replace(' ', '', $value); ?>
            <form method="GET" action="page.php?ders=<?= $item;?>" target="_blank" name="f1">
                 <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?= $item;?>">
                 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><?= $item;?> &raquo;</a>
             </form>
             <br>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```