# PHP SQL Check if form input exists in other table, then continue

Tags: php, sql, validation

I'm writing a form where I want the code to check if the inserted 'date' on which a participant wants to attend an event matches a 'date' in my events table. For the moment (even though 'date' as on the form input doesn't match any of the dates on the events table) users can register for any date without getting the validation error.

on the html-form "register.html" I have:

```
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date"> Date of attendence </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date"/>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
```

on "register.php" I have:

```
    <?php
        $date = $_POST['date'];

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','skay');
        if($conn->connect_error){
            echo "$conn->connect_error";
            die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
        } else {
    
            $date_check_query = "SELECT COUNT * FROM events WHERE date='$date'";
            $number_of_matches = mysqli_query($conn, $date_check_query);

            if ($number_of_matches = 0) {
                array_push($errors, "No planned events on this day");
            } else {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registrations(date) values(?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $date); //there are other 5 other values aswell
                $execval = $stmt->execute();
                echo $execval;
                echo "Registration successfully...";
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
            }
        }       
    ?>
```

Grtz Beau

Comment: Looks like you're using unescaped input in your first query. That's a little dangerous... Your prepared statement is a lot safer. What is your question?

Comment: `$number_of_matches` is not what you think at that point, so `if ($number_of_matches = 0)` is incorrect. Either find the number of affected rows ( num_rows ) or assign an alias to the `count(*)` and fetch that from the recordset

Comment: That prepared statement seems faulty. You need the same number of placeholders and parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you assign an `alias` to the value returned by `count(*)` - like `count(*) as 'aliasname'`, you can treat that as you would a regular column in the recordset.

Using a `prepared statement` to input data is fine but the good work is undone by using potentially malicious data directly in the `select` query - whereever you take user input you need to take extra precautions, so use prepared statements in all such cases.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['date'] ) ){
    
        $date = $_POST['date'];

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','skay');

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM `events` WHERE `date`=?";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($total);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        
        
        
        if( $total==0 ){
            $errors[]="No planned events on this day";
        }else{
            $sql='insert into `registrations`( `date` ) values(?)';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$date);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();             
            echo "Registration successfully...";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your code, especially here

```
if ($number_of_matches = 0) {
```

Should be

```
if ($number_of_matches == 0) {
```

It's not into the scope of your questions but it's good ti think about SQL injection attacks and rework the following line of code:

```
$date_check_query = "SELECT COUNT * FROM events WHERE date='$date'";
```

Comment: XSS concerns [web documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting), this here is [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Comment: You are correct!