# XSS Vulnerability in Html

Tags: xss, penetration-testing, veracode

how to fix this vulnerability?

```
<input type=hidden name=target value="$$target$$">
Injection Code

Injection
<input type=hidden name=target value="https://test/ff5b27051cb9fatest" accesskey=x onclick=alert(document.location)"">
```

Comment: Does it answer your questions :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940275/9368328

Comment: Yes @TonyStark.  Explanation is fine. Could you please re-write this <input type =hidden name = target value="$$target$$"> to fix vulnerability

Comment: What is the value for target? "$$target$$"?? and what is the use of it?

Comment: target value from Url.

Comment: You can use HtmlSanitizer for .NET  or encode the url

Comment: this is my Url: https://test-live.com/testing/forms/Login&TARGET=-HM-https%3a%2f%2ftest.com%2ftest%2fLKSDFSLDFK .              How to fix in my html code?

Comment: Please refer this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You are not encoding `"` characters. This allows the attacker to terminate your HTML attribute (`value`) and inject their own (`onclick`). As others have mentioned, you should use a trusted sanitizer, but the key vulnerability as you have shown is the failure to encode quotes.